# unity угол наклонности поверхности

Tags: unity3d

на игроке установлен CharacterController. Можно ли как-то узнать угол наклонности поверхности, на которой стоит игрок?

```
public float jumpSpeed = 8;
public float gravity = 20;
public float speed = 6;
CharacterController controller;
Vector3 moveDirection;

void Start () {
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}


void Update () {
    if (controller.isGrounded)
    {
        moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0.0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection) * speed;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
        }
    }
    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: Кстати, можно еще через коллизию найти обьект с тегом поверхности. А потом просто узнать угол наклонности обьекта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
float diff = -Vector3.Dot(forward.normalized, hit.normal)
```

Даст тебе отношение к наклону. Больше ноля - уклон по ходу движения, меньше ноля - против хода. 0 - ровно. Максимальные значения 1 и -1.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6dkpq1BDCNY

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Dot.html